# How to localize Display attribute in Asp.Net Core 1.0.0?

Tags: c#, localization, asp.net-core

How can i localize `Name` in `Display` attribute?
For example:

```
[Display(Name = "Library name")]
public string LibraryName { get; set; }
```

What should I do with that attribute?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ASP.NET Core 1.0 does not support out-of-the-box localization based on the new introduced localization approach for the `Display` attribute. One way to go is to use the prior to ASP.NET Core 1.0 approach for localization with resource files. I have implemented a simple demo project which shows how to localize the display attribute here https://github.com/feradz/ASPNetCoreLocalization/wiki `DataAnnotations.resx` is used for localizing the `Display` attribute.

In this approach the display name cannot contain special characters and spaces. For example the display name cannot be `Library name` but it can be `LibraryName`

```
[Display(Name="LibraryName", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.DataAnnotations))]
public string LibraryName { get; set; }
```

Comment: I don't know why, but it isn't working. I've done everything as suggested, but nothing happens.

Comment: Does the example from the github compile and run correctly?

Comment: I'll try it on Monday!

Comment: The project in the github demonstrates exactly what you need.

Answer (score -1):

From .net framework 4.6.2 released in early August 2016 localization has been made much easier.

Keep your view model class with the primary language data annotations in English e.g.

```
public class ContactInfo
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Your email address is invalid")]
    [Display(Name = "User Email")]
    public int Email { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Your phone number is invalid")]
    [Display(Name = "User Phone")]
    public int Phone { get; set; }
}
```

Create an `App_LocalResources` and add resource files using the convention `DataAnnotation.Localization.{locale}.resx` e.g. for Chinese `DataAnnotation.Localization.zh.resx` or `DataAnnotation.Localization.jp.resx` for Japanese

[image]

Then for the English annotation text in your viewmodel
e.g. "User Phone"

```
 [Display(Name = "User Phone")]
```

create an entry for the same English text in each language resource file you want your site to support

[image]

Read more [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/02/announcing-net-framework-4-6-2/) about this change in `.net 4.6.2`

I have excluded determining the culture that corresponds to the language file as this can go quite in depth. You can read more about it [in this blog post](http://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/how-aspnet5-determines-culture-info-for-localization) and in the [ASP.NET documentation](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/localization.html) site

Comment: Please, can you put example about this with ASP.NET Core 1.0. I never managed to use arbitrary strings as Display Name.

Comment: From my understanding this improvements are for ASP.NET and not for ASP.NET Core.

Comment: I'm downvoting as the OP explictly asked for .NET Core based scenario